# I am having trouble with pairing an IF else statement with a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

```
function calcPyth() {
    let v1 = document.getElementById("v1").value;
    let v2 = document.getElementById("v2").value;
    let v3 = document.getElementById("v3").value;

    if ((v1 * v1) == (v2*v2)+(v3*v3)) {
        alert("These are pythagoras triplets");
    } else if ((v1 * v1) < (v2*v2) + (v3*v3)) {
        alert("This is an obtuse triangle");
    } else {
        alert("This is an acute triangle");
    }
}
```

When I try to run to run the statement, it only returns the else if value.I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Well, first off, `v1, v2, v3` are all strings.  Doing math with strings generally has unexpected results.  Try parsing them into numbers first.

Comment: So your problem is that `"These are pythagoras triplets"` is not displayed? With which numbers does that occur?

Comment: @asdfgerte but hes not doing that.

Comment: @amy usually yes and that is a good tip, but its not related to the problem

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3u1hoq8z/

Comment: @JonasW. true. Skipping code too fast :)

Comment: `*` converts strings to numbers before applying multiplication.

Comment: @JonasW. With the numbers 3, 4, 5

Comment: `9` is *not* `16 + 25` ...

Comment: @Jonas W. I meant 5 squared would be equal to adding 3 squared plus 4 squared

Comment: Without being able to run your html code as well, it's impossible to tell for sure what's wrong. However, if you use your function like it's being used below, it works correctly

In this case, the first `if` returns `true` and is executed as supposed to the second one as you said.

My guess is that something is going wrong when you're getting the values from the `document`, making the values not what you expect them to be.

Comment: @wenpen and whats not working with that? Your code actually works then

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all possible combination for Pythagoras triplet.

```js
function calcPyth() {
    let v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value);
    let v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value);
    let v3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v3").value);

    if ((v1 * v1) == (v2*v2)+(v3*v3) || (v2 * v2) == (v1*v1)+(v3*v3) || (v3 * v3) == (v1*v1)+(v2*v2)) {
        alert("These are pythagoras triplets");
    } else if ((v1 * v1) < (v2*v2) + (v3*v3)) {
        alert("This is an obtuse triangle");
    } else {
        alert("This is an acute triangle");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="v1" value="3"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="v2" value="4"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="v3" value="5"/><br/>
<button onClick="calcPyth()">calcPyth</button>
```